# How come I can't execute my c# program in Xamarin Studios?

Tags: c#, xamarin

When I first installed Xamarin Studios for my mac it worked perfectly but now for some reason I can't run any of my codes. I get an error message that says Cannot execute "Users/hd...in/Debug/Assignment_2.exe". I don't know why this is the case and I didn't do anything weird to it. If I try running this without debug mode I still get the same issue. I already tried reinstalling but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running mono apps on mac you need to explicitly use mono, i.e. in the terminal type: `mono Assignment_2.exe`

Comment: So does that mean I need my terminal open from the mac?

Comment: I thought you were trying to execute from the terminal. You don't need your terminal open. If you want more help then attach the output of the build (View|Pads|Errors and the bottom right pane should display the build log.

Comment: It works now but it opens up a terminal to take in my input which I forgot it did before. I'm ok with it running from the terminal for now

Comment: Project options|Run|Configurations|Default and uncheck "Run on external console" if you want to change this behavior.

Comment: I uncheck run on external console and click run but it still shows up in the terminal.